# How does redis-cli encode the string values returned on executing a GET on HLLs or bitmaps?

Tags: go, encoding, redis

Suppose I have a bitmap that I have set using the following commands

```
setbit key 0 1
setbit key 1 1
setbit key 2 0
setbit key 3 1
setbit key 4 1
```

When I run get on this key from the redis-cli I get the following result: `"\xd8"`

But when I do it using a [go-redis API](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-redis/redis) I get a different result which is this: � @

To get the above result I have used the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/go-redis/redis"
)

func main() {
    client := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     "localhost:6379",
        Password: "",
        DB:       0,
    })

    pong, _ := client.Ping().Result()
    fmt.Println(pong)

    client.SetBit("key", 0, 1)
    client.SetBit("key", 1, 1)
    client.SetBit("key", 2, 0)
    client.SetBit("key", 3, 1)
    client.SetBit("key", 4, 1)  

    res := client.Get("bmk").Val()
    fmt.Println(res)

}
```

I cannot find it anywhere in the redis docs which kind of encoding the cli uses to produce such results. I would like to convert the results to the same format in my go program as well.

Can someone please tell me what kind of encoding this is and how can I convert the result received from the Redis API to the one obtained by the CLI ?

Comment: you can use  in `fmt.Printf("%v",res)` instead of `fmt.Println(res)`. It prints `bytes`.

Comment: No I want to store the data in a variable. How can I do that? @whitespace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The redis-cli and the Go program get the same result for GET on some key. The difference that you are observing is how the result value is formatted for output.

The Go program in the question writes the data as is.

The redis-cli code for encoding output is [here](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/febe102bf6d94428779f3943aea5947893301912/src/sds.c#L870-L899). The function uses typical backslash escapes for newlines, quotes, etc and `\x<hex number>` for other non-printable bytes.

Use the fmt package "%q" verb to output data in a similar format:

```
fmt.Printf("%q\n", res)
```

If you need the exact same format, then a translation of the internal Redis function to Go required.